# Blow-up of variety depends on the ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to prove that the blow-up of $\mathbb{A}^2$ at the ideal $\langle x_1^2,x_1 x_2,x_2^2\rangle$ is isomorphic to its blow-up at the ideal $\langle x_1, x_2\rangle$ and that this is not true in general, i.e. The blowup at a non-radical ideal $I$ is not necessarily the same that the blow-up at $\text{rad} (I)$.

I'm not sure how to do this, in particular, I have no idea about how to find the counterexample.

I use the following definition: The blow-up of $\mathbb{A^2}$ at $f=(f_1:\cdots:f_r):\mathbb{A}^2\to \mathbb{P}^{r-1}$ is given by the closure of the graph
$$\Gamma_f=\{(x,f(x))\mid x\in \mathbb{A}^2-V(f_1,\dots,f_r)\}.$$

To find the isomorphism I've tried the following:

I have an explicit formula for the blow-up at $\langle x_1,x_2\rangle$, it is
$$\{((x_1,x_2),[y_1:y_2])\in \mathbb{A}^2\times \mathbb{P}^1\mid x_1 y_2=x_2y_1\}.$$

I also know that points $((x_1,x_2),[y_1:y_2:y_3])$ of the blow-up a $\langle x_1^2,x_1 x_2,x_2^2\rangle$ satisfy the equations:
$$y_1 x_1 x_2=x_1^2 y_2,y_1 x_2^2=y_3 x_1^2, y_2 x_2^2=y_3 x_1 x_2,$$
So I suspect the blow-up at $\langle x_1^2,x_1 x_2,x_2^2\rangle$ is the set of all the elements satisfying that system of equations. I'm not sure how to see the isomorphism even if that were the case.

Comment: For the first question you need one more equation: $y_1y_3 = y_2^2$. For the second --- consider the blowup of the ideal $(x_1^2,x_2)$.

Comment: Sandor Kovacs' answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140230/blow-up-along-singular-variety) might also give you a little bit of an additional push in the right direction.